# Objective C repeated callback required

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks, nsnotificationcenter

I'm quite new to iOS development, and I've been trying to solve the following problem:

I have a `ViewController` displaying information that changes with time. I have another controller (`TimeController`) managing time. `TimeController` has an `NSTimer` firing every second to check whether I've entered a new time slot (there's some logic behind it, and if I've entered a new time slot that means that the information in the `ViewController` needs to be updated.

In my understanding, I need some kind of callback procedure but I couldn't figure out how to do it - I read about blocks but to be honest they're quite overwhelming and I couldn't relate my problem to the examples I saw.

The `TimeController` looks something like the following:

```m
// TimeController.h

@interface TimeController : NSObject

@property (weak) NSTimer *periodicTimer;
@property NSInteger timeslot;

@end

// TimeController.m
#import "TimeController.h"

@implementation TimeController

-(void)startTimer {
    self.periodicTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1) target:self 
             selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)onTimer {
    // check if anything has changed.
    // If so, change timeslot. Notify "listening" objects.
}
```

In a simple example with a single `ViewController` depending on `TimeController`, I'm imagining something like this:

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property TimeController* timeCtrl;

@end

// ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TimeController.h"

-(void)onNotificationFromTimeController {
    // timeslot has changed in the TimeController.
    NSInteger tslot = timeCtrl.timeslot;

    // figure out new display value depending on tslot. Update the view
}
```

What's missing here (among other stuff like proper initialisation of `timeCtrl`) are the callback mechanisms. I'd appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notifications**

Add a listener to the event (let's call it "TimeNotificationEvent") in `ViewController`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onNotificationFromTimeController) name:@"TimeNotificationEvent" object:nil];
```

In the `onTimer` method in `TimeController.m`, add the following code to post a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TimeNotificationEvent" object:nil];
```

Sidenote: To stop listening for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"TimeNotificationEvent" object:nil];
```

- Easy to setup
- You can have multiple listeners for the same event

**Blocks**

Add a property in `TimeController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t timerBlock;
```

Add a call to the timerBlock in `TimeController.m`:

```
-(void)onTimer {
    // Check for nil to avoid crash
    if (_timerBlock) {
        _timerBlock();
    }
}
```

Assign the block in `ViewController`:

```
_timeCtrl.timerBlock = ^{
    // Do stuff to the UI here
};
```

- A bit more complex (retain cycles, syntax etc)
- Only one listener (with this particular example implementation)
- Easier to follow the code

Comment: Wow, that's really elegant and seems to be exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks!

Comment: Added a quick example of a solution using blocks since you asked for blocks, but I believe notifications should work just fine

Comment: Thanks for the Block version as well! Notifications should be perfect for me actually - I just didn't know about them. I want multiple view controllers to be listening to the same timer. All the time I spent searching with the wrong keywords :)